# Download a Google Slides Presentation to a PDF Document

Tags: google-api, google-slides-api

I'm using google slide api to generate google slide presentation. but I want to convert this presentation on PDF unsing this API, I was looking in G-slide api but I didn't found anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via the Drive API's `export` method:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

Use `mimeType` "application/pdf" and the Slides `presentationId` as the Drive `fileId`.

Comment: Hi @Maurice Codik, Thank you for your replay, I see the Doc in link, but how I can specify the mimeType in this like `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export` I can put just the presentationId here ?

Comment: I found it,I didn't pay attention, I jsut need to add `/pdf` to the link above,Thank you @Maurice Codik